# What would be interesting maps to use on that Eudoxus reals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, real-numbers

I'm trying to understand Eudoxus Reals. From wikipedia:

> Let an **almost homomorphism** be a map $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ such that the set $\{f(n+m)-f(m)-f(n): n,m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is finite. We say that two almost homomorphisms $f,g$ are **almost equal** if the set $\{f(n)-g(n): n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is finite. This defines an equivalence relation on the set of almost homomorphisms. Real numbers are defined as the equivalence classes of this relation. To add real numbers defined this way we add the almost homomorphisms that represent them. Multiplication of real numbers corresponds to composition of almost homomorphisms. If $[f]$ denotes the real number represented by an almost homomorphism $f$ we say that $0\leq [f]$ if $f$ is bounded or $f$ takes an infinite number of positive values on $\mathbb{Z}^+$. This defines the linear order relation on the set of real numbers constructed this way.

I don't understand what $f$ could be. I know that it might be some map that follow the given conditions, but I don't know what would be an interesting/feasible function to use with this.

Comment: I think the interesting question is rather : how do you even represent a rational number using this notion of almost homomorphism? It doesn't seem trivial to guess.

Comment: Simplest may be an "affine linear" function, $f(x) = Mx + B$.

Comment: @lulu I don't get it. If I take $f(x)=mx+b$, I'd have:

$$f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y)=m(x+y)+b-(mx+b)-(my+b)=-b$$

That doesn't seems meaningful.

Comment: Isn't that what you want?  As I understand it (possibly incorrectly) you want the collection of values {$f(m+n)-f(m)-f(n)$} to be a finite set, yes?  For a true homomorphism it would be {0}, but you want something else.  In my example, the set  is a single value, -B.

Comment: @lulu Yes. But I'm not sure of what $f$ would be *useful* for this construction of the Eudoxus reals. I'm reading [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0405454v1.pdf) but it doesn't ring a bell.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were looking for natural examples of such functions.  I've never seen this construction before...I'll look it up.

Answer (score 1):

According to page 12 of the [document](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0405454v1.pdf) you mentioned in the comments:

> The Eudoxus real number representation is due to Stephen Schanuel and
>   dates back to the early 1980s. Schanuel observed that the graph of the function
>   p → ⌊xp⌋ is a subset of Z × Z that can be thought of a discrete representation
>   of the real quantity x.